# How to make "php -S" to work on local network?

Tags: php, server, lan

In OS X Mavericks (and newer), start a PHP server from the command line:

```
cd to/your/directory
php -S localhost:8888
```

It works, but the server only available on that computer only. Is there a way to test it on other devices within the same LAN?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

EDIT:

You will want to launch the server with the command

`php -S 0.0.0.0:8888`

This will allow you to access the server remotely (see docs http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)

After this is done there are 2 ways to view the site on your local network

`http://192.168.1.2:8888` where `192.168.1.2` is the IP address of your computer which you can find in your `System Preferences` under `Network`.

`http://myMac.local:8888` where `myMac` is your local computer name which you can find in your `System Preferences` under `Sharing`.

**REMEMBER**: Both of these options may require your firewall to allow incoming traffic to port 8888 (or whatever port your script is listening on), if you have that running.

Answer (score 10):

Start with:

`php -S 0.0.0.0:8888`

otherwise you bind the server to localhost;